# Network Simulator Code Explanation

Tags: ns2

```
set xx(0) 1.0
set yy(0) 1.0
$node_(0) set X_ $xx(0)
$node_(0) set Y_ $yy(0)


set g(1) $column

set g(2) [expr $g(1) + $column]

for {set i 3} {$i <= [expr $row -1]} { incr i } {

set g($i) [expr $g([expr $i - 1]) + $column]

}
set g(0) 0

set xx($g(1)) 1.0
set yy($g(1)) [expr $xx(0) + 100]
$node_($g(1)) set X_ $xx($g(1))
$node_($g(1)) set Y_ $yy($g(1))

for {set i 0} {$i <= [expr $row -1] } { incr i } {

set count($g($i)) 0

}
```

Can someone please tell me what is being done and use of every line in this code...!!
The use of xx(0) and yy(0)
also what is happening in g(0) g(1) and all.

Answer (score 0):

---

xx might mean x to x, but a for line with : set [something] [value]

... any random word can actually be used.

Explaining all lines : Not possible. Just some settings ( set [word] [?] )

The complete file is missing.

---

We have four  examples with xx and yy, from a Google search :

https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+set+xx(0)+1.0+set+yy(0)+1.0+%24node_(0)+set+X_+%24xx(0)

. http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-users/2013-November/073436.html

. http://www.ijcnwc.org/papers/vol2no52012/1vol2no5.pdf

. http://kalkanotel.com/modification-needs-to-make-aodv-protocol-work-with-mobilenode-my-source-is-fixed-node-and-my-destination-is-mobilenode-i290320.htm

. http://ns-2sourcecode.blogspot.dk/2013/01/to-set-nodes-destination-and-color.html

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)